# Rust complains about freed mutable borrow but not immutable borrow

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

The following two rust functions are identical other than the fact that one returns an immutable reference and the other returns a mutable one. Since neither involves borrowing something multiple times, I don't see why the two sould work any differently. However, the one with the mutable reference results in a compile error, while the one with the immutable reference does not:

```rust
// This complies with no problems
fn foo<'a>() {
    let _: &'a () = &();
}

// This does not compile (see error below)
fn foo_mut<'a>() {
    let _: &'a mut () = &mut ();
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:14:30
   |
13 | fn foo_mut<'a>() {
   |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
14 |     let _: &'a mut () = &mut ();
   |            ----------        ^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |            |
   |            type annotation requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
15 | }
   |  - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0716`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

It is also possibly relevant that when there are no explicit lifetimes, the code also has no problem compiling:

```rust
// This also compiles with no problem
fn foo_mut_without_lifetime() {
    let _: &mut () = &mut ();
}
```

It seems the only thing that is causing a problem is trying to store a mutable reference with a lifetime, and that immutable references and references without explicit lifetimes have no issue. Why is this happening, and how can I get around it?

Comment: "In simple cases where the & expression is immediately stored into a variable, the compiler will automatically extend the lifetime of the temporary until the end of the enclosing block." [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0716.html) I'm not sure what constitutes a simpler case here but maybe in the immutable example the temporary `()` is having it's lifetime  implicitly extended to the end of the func.

Comment: The lifetime of the mutable reference still can be extended to the whole function block but that's not enough. Since the caller can request any lifetime you have to be able to extend it to `'static` which is the only lifetime satisfiying every other lifetime. For `&()` this can safely be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there's nothing special about `()` or generic lifetimes here. This compiles fine:

```rust
fn allowed() -> &'static i32 {
    let x = &3;
    let y: &'static i32 = x;
    y
}
```

And this does not:

```rust
fn not_allowed() -> &'static mut i32 {
    let x = &mut 3;
    let y: &'static mut i32 = x;
    y
}
```

### So why is the immutable reference allowed?

When you take a reference of a value, Rust infers the lifetime based on where the value's going to die. Here's an example:

```rust
let y;
{
    let x = 3;
    y = &x;
    println!("{y}"); // works fine, `y` is still alive
} // `x` will get dropped at the end of this block
println!("{y}"); // fails to compile, the lifetime of `y` has expired (since `x` has died)
```

Since `x` dies at the end of the block, Rust knows that the lifetime of the `y` reference should only extend until the end of the block as well. Hence, it stops you from using it after `x` is dead.

This seems pretty obvious. But take a moment to think. In the following code:

```rust
let x;
{ // block A
x = &3;
}
```

What is the inferred lifetime of `x`? You may be tempted to say "the same as block A". But this would in fact be incorrect. Why? Because Rust is a bit smarter than that. It knows that `3` is a *constant*, and therefore Rust can fit `3` into the constant table of the final executable. And since the constant table will last as long as the lifetime of the final program, **Rust can infer that the expression `&3` has a `'static` lifetime.** Then everything works out fine, since `&'static` can be cast to any other lifetime as required!

Rust draws an explicit line between constants and temporaries, and one of the benefits of having a constant expression is that **taking an immutable reference of any constant will always yield a `'static` lifetime.** This is not true of temporaries. The following code will not compile:

```rust
fn f() -> &'static String {
    let x = &String::new();
    let y: &'static String = x;
    y
}
```

This is because for temporaries, Rust can't put them in the constant table of the executable, since they have to be computed on-demand, and therefore share the same lifetime as the scope they're in.

### Okay, this is great, but why isn't the *mutable* reference of a constant allowed to be `'static`?

There are two problems with allowing this:

1. On some architectures, constant tables can't be modified. This is true of WASM and some embedded architectures, as well as all Harvard-architecture machines. Providing a `&mut` reference would just be complete nonsense, since they're not mutable. And such fundamental borrow checker rules should really not differ between platforms.
2. A `&'static mut` reference is dangerous, since it is quite literally a global variable.

Comment: Note that technically it is possible to static-promote mutable references to ZSTs (as they occupy no bytes), and this was even mentioned in the RFC, and empty arrays even allow that.